# How to evade precompile error using Julia when adding packages

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am trying to use three different packages with Julia programming (with Atom IDE, for what it's worth).

I'm very new to Julia so pardon any ignorance! Here's what I've got:

```
Pkg.add("JuMP")
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("GLPKMathProgInterface")
```

These run successfully.

Then I have:

```
using DataFrames
using GLPKMathProgInterface
using JuMP
```

the "using DataFrames" line executes successfully, but after that I get a precompiling/installation error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: GLPK not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("GLPK")
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at /Users/connordaly/.julia/packages/GLPK/thMVo/src/GLPK.jl:199
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [6] top-level scope at none:2
 [7] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [8] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:399
 [9] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/connordaly/.julia/packages/GLPK/thMVo/src/GLPK.jl:196
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile GLPK [60bf3e95-4087-53dc-ae20-288a0d20c6a6] to /Users/connordaly/.julia/compiled/v0.7/GLPK/r6CoY.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1185
 [4] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./logging.jl:311
 [5] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:852
 [6] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:834
 [8] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [10] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [11] include(::String) at /Users/connordaly/.julia/packages/GLPKMathProgInterface/Ijibf/src/GLPKMathProgInterface.jl:2
 [12] top-level scope at none:0
 [13] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [14] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [15] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [16] top-level scope at none:2
 [17] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [18] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:399
 [19] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/connordaly/.julia/packages/GLPKMathProgInterface/Ijibf/src/GLPKInterfaceBase.jl:6
in expression starting at /Users/connordaly/.julia/packages/GLPKMathProgInterface/Ijibf/src/GLPKMathProgInterface.jl:10
ERROR: Failed to precompile GLPKMathProgInterface [3c7084bd-78ad-589a-b5bb-dbd673274bea] to /Users/connordaly/.julia/compiled/v0.7/GLPKMathProgInterface/Y5bTM.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1185
 [4] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [5] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:941
 [6] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:852
 [7] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [8] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:834
```

I have tried a bunch of things to get this package to work but no luck so far. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Being a new user to Julia, I assume you are trying this one version 1.0.  This announcement is relevant https://discourse.julialang.org/t/psa-use-julia-0-7-if-you-are-upgrading/13321.

Julia 0.7 has the same functionality as 1.0, but still has deprecation warnings for compatibility, which have been removed in 1.0.

Give Julia 0.7 a try for the time being.  You may also have add in a `Pkg.build("GLPK")` if you encounter that particular error again.